# How to get all the read more links of amazon.jobs with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a Beginner in Python, I just want to scrap all the read more links from amazon job page. for example, I want to scrap this page 
https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search?base_query=&loc_query=Greater+Seattle+Area%2C+WA%2C+United+States&latitude=&longitude=&loc_group_id=seattle-metro&invalid_location=false&country=&city=&region=&county=

Below is the code I used.

```
#import the library used to query a website
import urllib2
#import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data returned from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify the url
url = "https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search?base_query=&loc_query=Greater+Seattle+Area%2C+WA%2C+United+States&latitude=&longitude=&loc_group_id=seattle-metro&invalid_location=false&country=&city=&region=&county="

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
print soup.find_all("a")
```

Output:

```
[<a class="icon home" href="/en">Home</a>,
 <a class="icon check-status" data-target="#icims-portal-selector" data-toggle="modal">Review application status</a>,
 <a class="icon working" href="/en/working/working-amazon">Amazon culture &amp; benefits</a>,
 <a class="icon locations" href="/en/locations">Locations</a>,
 <a class="icon teams" href="/en/business_categories">Teams</a>,
 <a class="icon job-categories" href="/en/job_categories">Job categories</a>,
 <a class="icon help" href="/en/faqs">Help</a>,
 <a class="icon language" data-animate="false" data-target="#locale-options" data-toggle="collapse" href="#locale-options" id="current-locale">English</a>,
...
 <a href="/en/privacy/us">Privacy and Data</a>,
 <a href="/en/impressum">Impressum</a>]
```

I am getting links to only static elements in the page i.e which are constant for any query but I need the links to 4896 jobs. Can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You won't get the dynamic elements using `urllib`, as they are loaded with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed your request returns only static elements, because the job links are generated by js.  In order to get js generated content you'd need `selenium` or similar clients that run js.
However, if you inspect the HTTP traffic, you'll notice that the jobs data are loaded by XHR request to api: `/search.json`, which returns json data.

So, using `urllib2` and `json` we can get the total number of results and collect all the data,

```
import urllib2
import json

api_url = 'https://www.amazon.jobs/search.json?radius=24km&facets[]=location&facets[]=business_category&facets[]=category&facets[]=schedule_type_id&facets[]=employee_class&facets[]=normalized_location&facets[]=job_function_id&offset=0&result_limit={results}&sort=relevant&loc_group_id=seattle-metro&latitude=&longitude=&loc_group_id=seattle-metro&loc_query={location}&base_query={query}&city=&country=&region=&county=&query_options=&'
query = ''
location = 'Greater Seattle Area, WA, United States'
request = urllib2.urlopen(api_url.format(query=query, location=location, results=10))
results = json.loads(request.read())['hits']

request = urllib2.urlopen(api_url.format(query=query, location=location, results=results))
jobs = json.loads(request.read())['jobs']
for i in jobs:
    i['job_path'] = 'https://www.amazon.jobs' + i['job_path']
```

The `jobs` list holds a number of dictionaries with all the job information (title, state, city, etc). If you want to select a specific item - for example the links - just loop over the list and select that item.

```
links = [i['job_path'] for i in jobs]
print links
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response.
Yes, your suggestion solved the problem.
Thanks a lot, men.